# Is CSS the only way for styling HTML documents?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner web-designer. I know the basics of HTML, CSS and Javascript. I know that CSS used to style HTML docs, but is that the only way ? Can I use JavaScript to style HTML, somehow ? Or Is there any other way rather than CSS ?

Comment: Yes you can but you will be doing the same thing to add style..And as you are dioing java scrirpt or jquery it will add coplexity to page

Comment: I'm curious _why_ you would want to do it another way.

Comment: There are frameworks to try to make things easier, though as a beginner I'm not sure if using them is conducive to learning.  There are also extended versions of CSS (e.g., [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)) which add features to CSS that can make it less tedious to use.  Of course, in the end such tools still generate standard CSS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript is a scripting language, not a styling language. While you can use JavaScript to apply CSS, it's still CSS, not JavaScript, that's defining the styles.

There exist HTML presentational attributes from [a long time ago](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32), but those have been superseded by CSS. You can still use them, not that you would want to, considering they'll most likely get translated to CSS anyway.

There also exist CSS preprocessors with custom languages, such as [Sass/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com), [LESS](http://lesscss.org) and [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus), but they all compile to CSS as well, because that's what's actually implemented by browsers. So even if you use these preprocessors, at the end of the day you're still "writing" CSS.

Comment: Presentational attributes are not necessarily translated to CSS. That’s just how CSS specs say how they should be handled (without actually specifying any specifics). And they will take effect even when CSS is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that CSS used to style HTML docs, but is that the only way ?

It is the only sensible way

> Can I use JavaScript to style HTML, somehow ?

You can generate CSS with JavaScript. (Not advisable for general styling).

You can use [JSSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets) if you're only targeting Netscape 4.x.

Comment: Netscape 6 dropped support for JSSS? Shame.

Answer (score 1):

You're also able to style HTML with HTML-attributes itself, but this way is pretty impractical and old-fashioned. Most of these techniques are deprecated and the functionality is VERY limited.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the correct answer to your question is no, because html includes some basic style elements itself. But CSS is the best way to style your documents and you absolutely should learn and use it. Once you're comfortable using CSS, try using a framework such as [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the only way but the recommended way.
You can include styling in your html tags but it becomes messy.
That's why CSS was invented so use it !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, CSS is not the only way to stylize HTML but definitely the standard.  If you're looking for a more programmatic way utilizing JavaScript you can look into [less](http://lesscss.org/) which (taken directly from the webpage) ...extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions and functions map one-to-one with JavaScript code, allowing you to manipulate values however you want.